# Поиск первой и последней даты в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

Есть массив объектов с датами:

```
[{"name": "foo","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:30.3730"},{"name": "foo","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:29.3730"}, {"name": "bar","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:28.3730"}]
```

Необходимо найти первую и последнюю дату.
Делаю вот так но дата не записывается в объект:

```
let group = {};
    array.forEach(function(item) {
      if (!group[item.name]) {
        group[item.name] = {first: new Date(item.logTime)};
        group[item.name] = 0;
      }
      if (item.logTime > group[item.name].first) {
        group[item.name].first = item.logTime;
      }

      group[item.name]++;
    });
    console.log("group: ", group);
}
```

Comment: Как вариант (хоть и менее алгоритмически эффективный): отсортировать массив по дате и взять первый и последний элементы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const 
  arr = [
    {"name": "foo","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:30.3730"},
    {"name": "foo","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:29.3730"},
    {"name": "bar","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:28.3730"}
  ],
  group = {};
  
arr.forEach(checkDate);
console.log(group);

function checkDate(obj, index) {
  const date = new Date(obj.logTime);

  // Полагаем, что первая дата и первая, и последняя.
  if (index === 0) {
    group['first'] = group['last'] = { name: obj.name, logTime: date };
    return;
  };

  // Если текующая дата позже сохранненной последней, заменяем ее.
  if (date > group['last'].logTime) {
    group['last'] = { name: obj.name, logTime: date };
  };

  // Если текующая дата раньше сохранненной первой, заменяем ее.
  if (date < group['first'].logTime) {
    group['first'] = { name: obj.name, logTime: date };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал немного по-другому, чем вы, но так как вы просили:

```js
var array =
[
 {"name": "foo","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:30.3730"},
 {"name": "foo","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:29.3730"},
 {"name": "bar","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:28.3730"}
];

var group = {};

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
 if(!group[array[i].name] && i == 0)
 {
  group[array[i].name] = {first: new Date(array[i].logTime)};
 }

 if(!group[array[i].name] && i == array.length - 1)
 {
  group[array[i].name] = {last: new Date(array[i].logTime)};
 }
};
console.log("group: ", group);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну и немношк редьюсМеджик:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'foo', logTime: '2017-10-04T15:10:30.3730' },
  { name: 'foo', logTime: '2017-10-04T15:10:29.3730' },
  { name: 'bar', logTime: '2017-10-04T15:10:28.3730' }
];

const dates = arr.reduce((
  {
    first, first: { logTime: firstLogTime } = {},
    last, last: { logTime: lastLogTime } = {}
  },
  cur
) => {
  const curDate = new Date(cur.logTime);
  
  return {
    first: firstLogTime && new Date(firstLogTime) < curDate ? first : cur,
    last: lastLogTime && new Date(lastLogTime) > curDate ? last : cur
  }
}, {});
  
console.log(dates);
```

P.S. Что-то после правки "под условия задачи" читаемость упала, но тем не менее ...

Answer (score -1):

```js
var arr1 = [{"name": "foo","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:30.3730"},{"name": "foo","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:29.3730"}, {"name": "bar","logTime": "2017-10-04T15:10:28.3730"}];

var small, big;

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++ ) {
  if (!small || arr1[i].longTime < small.logTime) {
    small = arr1[i];
  }
  
  if (!big || arr1[i].longTime > big.logTime) {
    big = arr1[i];
  }
}

console.log("big: ", big);
console.log("small: ", small);
```